# How to load encoded public key using Kotlin PublicKey object in Python using cryptography

Tags: java, python, cryptography, python-cryptography

I'm currently having problems loading public keys "extracted" from Kotlin in Python. I'm trying to create a functional X25519 EDH between Kotlin and Python, so I need to load public key created by Kotlin code inside Python. The other way around works just fine.

My Kotlin code looks like this

```
class EllipticDiffieHellman {
    private val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("XDH")
    private val parameters = NamedParameterSpec("X25519")
    private val keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("XDH")
    private val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("XDH")

    fun generateKeyPair() : KeyPair {
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(parameters)
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
    }

    fun getKeyShare(keyPair: KeyPair) : ByteArray = keyPair.public.encoded

    fun bytesToPubKey(keyShare: ByteArray) : PublicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec(keyShare))

    fun getSharedKey(keyPair: KeyPair, keyShare: PublicKey) : ByteArray {
        keyAgreement.init(keyPair.private)
        keyAgreement.doPhase(keyShare, true)
        return keyAgreement.generateSecret()
    }
}

...

    val EDH = EllipticDiffieHellman()
    val keypair_python = EDH.generateKeyPair()
    File("keyshare_kotlin").writeBytes(EDH.getKeyShare(keypair_python))
```

When I try loading the same ByteArray using `bytesToPubKey`, everything works just fine.
Now for my Python code (a part of it):

```
import cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization as serialization
with open("keyshare_kotlin", "rb") as f:
    keyshare_kotlin = f.read()
loaded_public_key = serialization.load_der_public_key(keyshare_kotlin)
```

This doesn't work. I've been trying using other `cryptography`'s loading functions, but none work.

I'm getting `ValueError: Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format or it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm.`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The code looks correct to me. It might be that the backend does not recognize the OID for the EC 25519 public key, although that would be disappointing. I'll see if I can find the relevant source code to see what might be happening.

Comment: After some digging I found a kind of working solution - when I was encoding public keys in Python I noticed the output is 44 bytes long. Meanwhile, the output from Java/Kotlin is 46 bytes long. The only difference between these two "versions" are the first 12/14 bytes. The solution that works in my case is that instead of calling `load_der_public_key(keyshare_kotlin)` I call `load_der_public_key(public_bytes[:12] + keyshare_kotlin[14:])`, where `public_bytes` is the output of public key generated in Python(`.public_key().public_bytes(serialization.DER, serialization.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)`).

Comment: I'm glad you found a workaround but I'm still concerned that there might be a bug, or at least unexpected limitation, in the cryptography module. I traced the problem to a call to openssl function `d2i_PUBKEY_bio()` but from there I got lost in OpenSSL's distinctive macro hell and couldn't proceed further. By the way, please post your workaround with code as an answer. Comments can get deleted, answers are forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution, although as mentioned in the comments - it isn't optimal.

Bytes generated by Kotlin/Java use different header than bytes generated by Python. While Kotlin's header is 14 bytes long, Python's header is 12 bytes long. This is the only difference between these two "versions" of encoded public keys and while Python is able to load the 12-byte header, it is unable to load Kotlin's 14-byte header.

Using a header extracted from bytes encoded using cryptography's `.public_key().public_bytes(serialization.DER, serialization.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)` and replacing the Kotlin's generated header with it it is possible to load the encoded bytes in Python.

```
import cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.x25519 as x25519
import cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization as serialization

private_key = x25519.X25519PrivateKey.generate()
public_bytes = private_key.public_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
        format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)

with open("keyshare_kotlin", "rb") as f:
        keyshare_kotlin = f.read()
loaded_keyshare = serialization.load_der_public_key(public_bytes[:12] + keyshare_kotlin[14:])
```